# Why do Express GET requests return HTML?

Tags: reactjs, express, get

I have an issue with my API GET routes always returning HTML. For example, I have this piece of code here:

```
router.get("/allposts", auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const Posts = await Post.find()
            .populate("postedBy","_id name")
            .populate("comments.postedBy","_id name")
            .sort("-createdAt");
        res.json(Posts)
        console.log(Posts)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({error: err.message});
    }
 });
```

And as a result it returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

How am I supposed to get data from the front end if it returns the code as HTML?

If I change `router.get` to `router.post` then it returns a JSON response, but all GET requests return HTML.

Here is my app.js:

```
const path = require("path")
const express = require("express")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const cors = require("cors")
const mongoSanitize = require("express-mongo-sanitize")
require("dotenv").config()

// start app
const app = express()
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

// Express port
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

// CORS
app.use(cors())

// Serve static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')))

// Sanitize against NoSQL query injections
app.use(mongoSanitize())

// Setting up a route for our API
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).json({
        status: "success"
    })
})

// Redirect back to index.html if urls do not match
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/build", "index.html"))
})

// Database
mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Database is connected.")
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Database connection was unsuccessful.")
        console.log(err)
        process.exit(1)
    })

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
})

app.get('/about', function (req, res) {
    res.send('about')
})

app.use('/users', require('./Routes/userRouter'))
app.use('/posts', require('./Routes/postRouter'))
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How are determining that it is returning HTML?  Are you looking at the response directly in Javascript or directly in the Chrome debugger? Or are you putting this URL in the URL bar in the browser and just seeing what the browser tries to display to you? I ask because unless you have something else installed in your server that is wrapping every response in HTML, then your server sends only what is sends and the route you ask about sends JSON, not HTML. If you put JSON into a browser window, the browser will wrap it in HTML just to show it to you, but that has nothing to do with what was sent.

Comment: I'm using Insomia

Comment: What is Insomnia?

Comment: It's similar to POSTMAN. Allows for API calls and it shows the result

Answer (score 0):

Because the endpoint /allposts which should be POST method does not exist and you are not handling 404 routes.

Below all endpoints registered in your app you might want to add something like this to handle 404 routes.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).json({ message: "Route not found" });
})
```

As for your case all the get requests fall into this middleware

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/build", "index.html"))
})
```